# Sum of Closed Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are two closed operators on a Hilbert space (not defined everywhere), is their sum closed as well? I think not, but cannot construct a counterexample. Some posts on this site do address this but they are not complete. For example,[Sum of Closed Operators Closable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53954/sum-of-closed-operators-closable)

gives two operators and shows that their sum is not cloasable, but does not show that the operators themselves are closed. There is another post saying the same thing

[Counterexample for "the sum of closed operators is closable"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361844/counterexample-for-the-sum-of-closed-operators-is-closable) but the question is still unresolved. Could someone give a different, simpler counterexample?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61161/sum-of-two-closed-operators-closable

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:D(A)\subset X\to Y$ be any closed operator with $D(A)\subset X$ not a closed set. Then $B=-A:D(A)\subset X\to Y$ is another closed operator.

Note that $A+B:D(A)\subset X\to Y$ is the zero operator which is not closed as its closure is the zero operator $\overline{D(A)}\subset X\to Y$.