# Is image of sum of maps closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $V$, $W$ are Banach spaces and $f$, $g:V \rightarrow W$ are continuous linear operators and $\operatorname{Im}f$, $\operatorname{Im}g$ are closed subspaces of $W$. Is it true that $\operatorname{Im}(f+g)$ is closed too?

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53954/sum-of-closed-operators-closable).